# discord.py TextChannel.edit() returns TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, typeerror, discord.py

I have this code for a bot command that sets a custom slowmode on a channel:

```py
if message.author.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_channels:
    if slowmode > 21600:
        await ctx.send('The maximum possible slowmode is 21600, or 6 hours.')
    elif slowmode < 0:
        await ctx.send('The minimum possible slowmode is 0, or no slowmode.')
    else:
        try:
            await ctx.message.channel.edit(reason='setcustomslowmode', slowmode_delay=slowmode)
            await ctx.send(f'Set the slowmode of channel <#{ctx.message.channel.id}> to **{slowmode}** seconds.')
        except discord.Errors.Forbidden:
            await ctx.send("I'm not allowed to do that, update my permissions and try again.")
else:
    await ctx.send('You need the permission `manage channel` to do this!')
```

It returns this traceback:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "discordbot.py", line 1212, in on_message
    await message.channel.edit(reason='Eric Bot /setcustomslowmode', slowmode_delay=int(subcommand[0]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 235, in edit
    await self._edit(options, reason=reason)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 285, in _edit
    self._update(self.guild, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 131, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_new'
```

The code that edits the channel works correctly (the slowmode is changed correctly), however the notification afterward stating that the slowmode was successfully changed never sends.

I've tried removing the `reason=` argument to `edit()`, but it just silently changes the slowmode and raises an exception, just like before.

[This](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.edit) doesn't mention anything about the error and it looks like I am using the function correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your discord library version. This error has been fixed. Update to version 1.3.4 and error will be fixed.

`python -m pip install -U discord.py`